# Which language has syntax like this

Tags: template-engine

Can any one let me know which language has syntax like this.
I know this is  a stupid question.

```
<<if $variable is 1>>Okay. I know.
<<elseif $variable is 0>>I don't know <<endif>>
```

Comment: What's with the seemingly-random tags? *Where* have you seen this syntax?

Comment: Why have you chosen those particular tags, [tag:generics], [tag:functional-programming], and [tag:artificial-intelligence]? I don't see how they relate to the question.

Comment: i was confuse about what to choose but i think people from these will have answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some kind of template substitution languages like the ones used in most web frameworks.

The idea is that the program is written directly as the expected output (often some sort of "document") in which some parts are substituted with variables and/or computed.

To mark these parts you use `<<...>>`.

It's a model of programming that pays off for simple case of outputs. For very complex outputs normally a fully procedural approach is better (i.e. where you actually build the document with normal functions and then output it).

Writing a templating engine is quite simple but somehow rewarding. As a consequence there is [a gajillion of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines) around (note that that list is about stand-alone templating engines, there are also a lot of website editors that implement their own template syntax).

Unfortunately the syntax `<<...>>` is hard to search for to find what programs use this custom language for template substitution.

Comment: yes the file is in .txt and it shows question and then few buttons, can you name any specific language?

Comment: You're not looking for a general purpose language, but for a specific program embedding a custom language. It's very simple to write a templating engine and therefore there are a jillion of them... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines.